# Getter returns a rvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

I know it's a bad attempt but why we cannot edit the private member via the getter?

```
class A
{
    int a = 2;
public:
    int GetA1() { return a; }
    int& GetA2() { return a; }
    int* GetA3() { return &a; }
};
int main() {
    A test;
    test.GetA1() = 4;     

    test.GetA2() = 4;     
    int b = test.GetA2(); 

    int* pb = &b;
    test.GetA3() = pb;
}
```

I think `GetA1()` doesn't work because it's using a rvalue, the copy by return. But then I'm a little surprised that `GetA2()` can work and at last really confused that `GetA3()` cannot work.

It seems that the value on member's address can be changed, but the address itself not. Does `GetA3` returns a rvalue or an unmodifiable lvalue?

Thanks!

Comment: `test.GetA3() = pb;` doesn't work because `test.GetA3()` doesn't return an lvalue reference. The value held by a pointer (an address) is still just a value. Other than the types there is no different in failure reason than the failure in `test.GetA1() = 4;`

Comment: You **can** modify the stored value via `GetA3`, try `*(test.GetA3()) = 42;`  This also is modifying the value at that address, not the address itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that the value on member's address can be changed, but the address itself not.

Indeed. More generally, it isn't possible to change the address where any object is stored. This applies to all objects.

> Does GetA3 returns a rvalue or an unmodifiable lvalue?

`GetA3()` is an rvalue, more specifically it is a prvalue (just like `GetA1()` is also a prvalue). The type of the prvalue is "pointer to int" (unlike the type of `GetA1()` which is just int).

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `test.a` with either `GetA2` or `GetA3`. What you can't do is assign to the prvalue `int *` that `GetA3` returns.

```
int main() {
    A test;
    // test.GetA1() = 4; // can't assign to a prvalue int

    test.GetA2() = 4; // can assign to a lvalue int
    int * pa = &test.getA2(); // can take the address of an lvalue

    int b = test.GetA2(); 

    int* pb = &b;
    // test.GetA3() = pb; // can't assign to a prvalue int *
    *test.GetA3() = 4; // can assign to a lvalue int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Value category's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#Mixed_categories):

> An rvalue can't be used as the left-hand operand of the built-in assignment or compound assignment operators.

Now we can make use of the above quoted statement to understand what is happening in your code.

---

The call expression `test.GetA1()` is an **rvalue** of type `int` and so cannot appear on the left hand side of an assignment.

While the call expression `test.GetA2()` is an **lvalue** of type `int` and so can appear on the left hand side of an assignment.

Similarly, the call expression `test.Get3()` is an **rvalue** of type `int*` and so cannot be used on the left hand side of an assignment.

> Does GetA3 returns a rvalue or an unmodifiable lvalue?

As described above, the value category of the expression `test.GetA3()` is an **rvalue**.